# Google Play book app price

Tags: android, google-play

Google Play changed my book App's price from $4.99 to $5.07. In the app settings the price is still $4.99. Why is Google changing the price and how do I get the price that I want?

Comment: Voted to close as this is question is not related to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not really a question related to programming and as such shouldn't be on SO. I expect that your issue is regarding sales tax that is applied to the price you enter in the Play Store.